# Evaluation metrics for Kmeans clustering in pyspark ML lib

Tags: pyspark, k-means, metrics, evaluation

can anyone please share any evaluation metrics used for KMeans clustering in pyspark ML libraray. Except Silhouette or SSE score, which I already have calculated.
I found a couple of metrics but they are available in scikit library of python but I am working in pyspark, example Calinski-Harabasz Index to name.

Comment: I am not aware of any implementation of this metric in pyspark. Anyhow, you may want still to use sklearn to compute it, while cluster labels could be generated via MLib